# Show encoded data from Redis

Tags: angularjs, node.js, redis

I have encoded data

```
"{\"brand\":\"newBrand\",\"Id\":\"1\",\"field\":\"1\",\"date\":1437487498449,\"period\":2,\"newUser\":0}"
```

which I publish with command: `PUBLISH channel "{\"brand\":\"newBrand\",\"Id\":\"1\",\"field\":\"1\",\"date\":1437487498449,\"period\":2,\"newUser\":0}"`

Then I retrieve these data (Node.js) and successfully show them on the frontend (Angular) in one line as a message. 
I want to show them in table(UI grid) - (column1 - Id, column2 - brand etc.)

Is there a way to parse these data to show them separately (every piece of data in appropriate column) in the table?

Comment: `var parsedData = JSON.parse("{\"brand\":\"newBrand\",\"Id\":\"1\",\"field\":\"1\",\"date\":1437487498449,\"period\":2,\"newUser\":0}")`

Answer (score 0):

In angular, to display data in a table you can use 'ng-repeat'.For details go through this URL:http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_tables.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` then use `ng-repeat`

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse("{\"brand\":\"newBrand\",\"Id\":\"1\",\"field\":\"1\",\"date\":143748‌​7498449,\"period\":2,\"newUser\":0}")
```

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_tables_simple

Comment: I publish data from redis client with PUBLISH command. I tried to parse data with JSON.parse, but I got SyntaxError: Unexpected token y
at Object.parse (native)